# "Не предоставляют информацию" или "информации"?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

На сайте газеты Коммерсант, https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3874009:

- заголовок: Власти Кабо-Верде не предоставляют **информацию** о возможном наказании российским морякам
- в основном тексте статьи: Органы Кабо-Верде пока не предоставляют  **информации** о том, какое наказание может грозить российским морякам.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильны оба варианта.

Объяснение зависит от того, каким определением падежа мы пользуемся:

- по Успенскому<sup>1</sup> (и Колмогорову) после отрицаемых глаголов существительные находятся в лишительном падеже, который имеет две формы, совпадающие с формами винительного и родительного падежей;
- по Зализняку<sup>2</sup> после отрицаемых глаголов возможно употребление как винительного, так и родительного падежей.

Но в обоих толкованиях правильны оба варианта.

Есть определенные случаи, когда употребление той или иной формы предпочтительнее (преимущественно для сохранения ясности), но в данной формулировке возможны оба варианта:

*не предоставлять информацию*

*не предоставлять информации*

---

1. Успенский В.А. К определению падежа по А. Н. Колмогорову / Бюллетень Объединения по проблемам машинного перевода. – 1957. – №. 5
2. Зализняк А.А. Русское именное словоизменение. — М.: «Наука», 1967.

Comment: Но все же, на мой взгляд, "информации" лучше. Заменим слово "информация" на "сведения". Вариант "Не предоставили сведения" выглядит заметно менее изящным, чем "Не предоставили сведений".

Comment: @JKlen Во-первых, речь о глаголе "предоставлять". Во-вторых, по А. Н. Колмогорову. В- третьих, _после отрицаемых глаголов_ — **всех** отрицаемых глаголов или каких-то особенных? В-четвертых, где же ссылки? В-пятых, единственное, что можно понять: _возможны оба варианта_. Без примеров, без объяснения предпочтительности. Не зря же торопливый автор задает дополнительные вопросы.

Comment: @JKlen  Грань между Р.п. и В.п., конечно, весьма размытая, но вот серьезные люди (Розенталь и другие ученые) занимались этой проблемой и старались найти решение для каждого конкретного случая,  так что не совсем понятно, о чем же вы сожалеете. Да, русский язык имеет определенные тонкости, оттенки и нюансы (как и всякий язык, вероятно), поэтому подходить к  его изучению нужно не с сожалением, а с любовью и вниманием.

Comment: Оба варианта правильны, но только _порознь_. Проблема в том, что у одного и того же автора разные варианты (журналист их явно не различает) призваны выразить одну и ту же мысль. Вариант с винительным падежом наводит читателя на мысль, что автор _предполагает_ наличие информации (принятое решение о наказании), обладатель которой её не сообщает. Второй же вариант указывает на полное _неведение_ автора о существовании такой информации (возможно, информации нет и у тех, кто принимает решение). Поэтому употребление двух разных падежных вариантов в одном и том же контексте выглядит как небрежность.

Answer (score 2):

**1.  Выбираем падеж по Розенталю**

Я полагаю, что основным учебным пособием для решения большинства проблем  является  **«Практическая стилистика» Розенталя.**  В частности тема выбора Р.п.или В.п. при отрицании изложена в §81. Варианты падежных форм дополнения при переходном глаголе с отрицанием.

Розенталь говорит о том, что в XVIII веке  (во времена Ломоносова) единственно правильным считался Р.п., однако уже в XIX веке  В.п. стал рассматриваться в качестве возможного и нормативного.  Тогда стала решаться задача о разграничении области применения этих падежей. Розенталь называет **ряд факторов**, но среди них можно выбрать основные:

(1) усиленное (Р.п.) или ослабленное (В.п.) отрицание;

(2) отвлеченный (Р.п.)  или конкретный  (В.п.) предмет;

(3) наличие партитивного (количественного) значения (Р.п.) или отсутствие  такого значения (В.п.).

(4) книжный (Р.п.) или разговорный  (В.п.) стиль;

(5) устойчивость сочетания (выбор падежа определяется традицией).

**2. Выбор варианта в заданном тексте**

На сайте газеты Коммерсант, https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3874009:

(1) заголовок: Власти Кабо-Верде **не предоставляют информацию** о возможном наказании российским морякам

(2) в основном тексте статьи: Органы Кабо-Верде **пока не предоставляют информации о том,** какое наказание может грозить российским морякам.

Оба варианта представляются корректными, там можно увидеть влияние различных факторов.

В предложении (1)  основным фактором является **конкретность**: сразу после существительного следует его определение: информации (какой?).

В предложении (2)  можно обратить внимание **на  подчеркнутое отрицание** и наличие **количественного значения** (= пока не предоставляют никакой, хотя бы частичной информации на указанную тему), в то время как **конкретность темы уже  отодвинута на второй план**, в том числе грамматическими средствами (это уже не определение, а определительное придаточное).

Оба варианты выглядят вполне приемлемыми, также можно предположить, что автор делает выбор не сознательно, а интутивно (на слух).

**3.  Отзыв на первый ответ**

Я вижу в ответе весьма существенные недостатки:

(1)  То, что оба падежа при отрицании возможны,  **является общеизвестным фактом**, и  от того, каким определением мы пользуемся, ничего не зависит. **«Лишительный падеж»  по Успенскому** практически нужен для решения проблем машинного перевода, а при рассмотрении практических задач можно обойтись и без него.

(2)  Конкретные факторы при выборе падежа указаны **у Розенталя**, в ответе же падеж фактически **не выбран и никак не обоснован**.

Нет, это не тот ответ, который здесь нужен. Вопрос же ставился так:  почему в одном тексте использованы **две формы, это случайно или нет?** Здесь могут быть разные мнения, но мнение автора ответа мы так и не услышали.

Примечание.

Но все-таки, чтобы «не красить все черной краской»,  для себя  отмечу наличие **полезной информации об Успенском В.А.**, о котором я мало что знала раньше.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

**Дополнительные материалы к ответу** (выдающиеся российские лингвисты,  которые имели отношение к  данной теме)

1. Обратим внимание на то, что практической стилистикой занимался **именно Розенталь,**  он является автором многих учебников и популярных книг о правильности речи: https://www.livelib.ru/author/3768/top-ditmar-rozental

Я полагаю, что основным учебным пособием для решения большинства проблем  является его «Практическая стилистика». В частности тема выбора Р.п.или В.п. при отрицании изложена в §81. Варианты падежных форм дополнения при переходном глаголе с отрицанием.

Этот материал в более краткой форме можно прочитать [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)  §201. **Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием.**

2. В предыдущем ответе  давались **другие ссылки**:  (1) Успенский В.А. К определению падежа по А. Н. Колмогорову / Бюллетень Объединения по проблемам машинного перевода. – 1957. – №. 5. (2) Зализняк А.А. Русское именное словоизменение. — М.: «Наука», 1967.

Эти лингвисты также внесли большой вклад в развитие науки, но их основные труды посвящены **другим темам**. В любом случае выбор падежа при отрицании  они не рассматривали так подробно, как Розенталь.

**Справочный материал**

Здесь я особо останавливаюсь **на трудах Успенского В.А.**   Он  заинтересовал меня сведениями о количестве падежей, которое приходится учитывать при машинном переводе, а также своим мнением о связи точных и гуманитарных наук. Здесь я с ним полностью согласна и считаю, что **строгость математического мышления гуманитариям необходима  не меньше,  чем математикам.**

(1) **Ди́тмар Элья́шевич Розента́ль (1900 — 1994)** — советский и российский лингвист, автор многочисленных трудов по русскому языку. Он считается родоначальником (вместе с профессором К. И. Былинским) практической стилистики, одним из основных разработчиков и истолкователей правил современного русского правописания. Автор более 100 учебников, пособий, справочников, словарей, популярных книг, а также исследовательских работ по русскому языку, культуре речи, стилистике, правописанию.

**(2) Андре́й Анато́льевич Зализня́к (1935 — 2017).** Основные труды:  общая лингвистика,  индоевропеистика и история языкознания, работы по древнерусскому языку и литературе,  акцентология. Но  главное практическое значение имеет его Грамматический словарь.

Из Википедии: **Классический «Грамматический словарь русского языка»** (1977, 4-е изд. 2003[19]), **где для 100 тыс. слов русского языка указана точная модель словоизменения** (и предложена классификация самих этих моделей). Словарь, составленный А. А. Зализняком **вручную**, стал основой практически для всех **компьютерных программ автоматического морфологического анализа** (в том числе в информационном поиске, в машинном переводе и т. п.).

(3) **Влади́мир Андре́евич Успе́нский (1930  —  2018)** — советский и российский математик, лингвист, публицист, популяризатор науки. Автор работ по математической логике, лингвистике, Инициатор реформы лингвистического образования в России. Доктор физико-математических наук (1964), профессор, заслуженный профессор Московского университета (1998).

В. А. Успенский в своих статьях, эссе и интервью утверждал, что **математика близка к гуманитарному знанию.** Учёный, по собственному признанию, был удивлён тем, что его статьи «Апология математики, или О математике как части духовной культуры» и «Гуманитарное и математическое: преодоление барьера» были опубликованы в литературных журналах «Новый мир» и «Знамя». Это подтвердило его версию о праве математики на место в общественном сознании и в духовной культуре — он считал важным хотя бы намекнуть, что математика помогает лучше понять устройство окружающего нас мира.

Главная цель обучения гуманитариев математике — **психологическая**. Эта цель состоит не столько в сообщении знаний и даже не столько в обучении методу, сколько **в расширении психологии обучающегося, в привитии ему строгой дисциплины мышления.** Помимо дисциплины мышления,  есть ещё **три важнейших умения**, выработке которых должны способствовать математические занятия. Первое — это умение отличать истину от лжи; второе — умение отличать смысл от бессмыслицы; третье  — умение отличать понятное от непонятного.

**В русском языке — 15 падежей**, а не 6, как учат в школе. Детально с этой проблемой столкнулись в середине 50-х годов, когда стали пытаться построить алгоритм математического анализа языка (математическая лингвистика). Этой проблемой занимался А.Колмогоров. Вот тогда и столкнулись **с невозможностью построить программу только с использованием 6 школьных падежей**. По этому поводу в МГУ была целая дискуссия. Успенский В. А «К определению падежа по А. Н. Колмогорову»
(1957, Опубликовано в продолжающемся сборнике: Бюллетень Объединения по проблемам машинного перевода. — № 5. — М.: 1957.

**12) Лишительный падеж** — используется исключительно с глаголами отрицания: не хочу знать правды (не правду), не может иметь права (не право).